# Should this data be organized into a table or a series of divs?

Tags: html, django

Recently at work there has been some discussion as to how best present a bit of data, and there seems to be some internal conflict as to whether or not certain pages should use tables to display the information vs. creating psuedo-tables with Bootstrap.

This is what source would look like if tables we decided to go ahead and use tables to display the information. Some of the conditional guff has been removed.

```
  <table class="table well">
  <thead>
      <th> Name </th>
      <th> Detail #1 </th>
      <th> Detail #2 </th>
      <th> Detail #3 </th>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="sortable">
  {% for m in model_list %}
      <tr id="{{ m.id }}">

          <td><span class='number-style'> {{ forloop.counter }}.</td>
          <td>{{ m.name}}</td>
          <td>{% autoescape off %}{{ m.detail1 }}{% endautoescape %} </td>
          <td>{% autoescape off %}{{ m.detail2}}{% endautoescape %} </td>
          <td>{% autoescape off %}{{ m.detail3}}{% endautoescape %} </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
```

and this is it using bootstrap divs

```
{% for m in model_list %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="span2">
    {{ m.name }}
    </div>

    <div class="span2" style="word-wrap: break-word">
        {% autoescape off %}{{ m.details1 }}{% endautoescape %}
    </div>

    <div class="span2" style="word-wrap: break-word">
        {% autoescape off %}{{ m.details2 }}{% endautoescape %}
    </div>

    <div class="span2" style="word-wrap: break-word">
        {% autoescape off %}{{ m.details3 }}{% endautoescape %}
    </div>

</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Keeping in mind that both of these are contained within a page laid out with bootstrap, and that their may be multiple instances of each of these "tables" on the page. Which method would be more generally preferred?

Comment: `<table>`s are exactly what you're using them for - tabular data.

Comment: There seems to be some disagreement within the office of what exactly the definition of tabular data is.

Comment: is this something you could present in an Excel spreadsheet or Access DB? Then it's tabular data.

Answer (score 0):

Do each and every row have the same datatype for detail 1? Similarly for detail 2 and 3?
If the relation between the rows is that all have 3 details but those 3 details can be of various types and not specifically of type 1, type 2 and type 3, then using table is NOT the right way.

For eg if I am listing books and their details are fixed and of type [author, category,  cost], then I would definitely use a table.

But if for some books I'm listing [author, category, cost], for some I'm listing [author, publisher, edition] and for others a different set altogether, then table is not the right way. Tables should not be used for visual styling and arrangement.

Seeing your code I get a strong feeling that details are of same data type and hence should be presented in a table.

Comment: The datatype for each one would technically be the same. They'd be block of text as far as the client has specified. For example, {{ m.name }} would be a task to perform. And {{ m.detail[1,2,3] }} would be 3 blocks of instructions for that task.   


I don't know precisely why it's organized this way but it's what our client seems to have asked for.

Comment: Something like step 1, step 2 and step 3 for that task? This doesn't seem to be data that would be put in a tabular form. If each task is separate and their instructions are unique to them I think it would be better if those rows are separated and put in divs.

Comment: I should point out that I'm aware there is obviously a cleaner and prettier way to lay this out. But the client wants to users to be able to use see the entire list of tasks and the instructions associated at one time (no scrolling, if possible)

Comment: Ah, they're not necessarily steps as far as I know. Maybe think of them as things to keep in mind during the task. (I'm being vague, sorry, but I'm trying to stay away from specifics)

Comment: Unless users are supposed to **compare** the tasks on the basis of what they'll have to "keep in mind", use divs. I guess even otherwise use divs. This is clearly not tabular data. What you are trying to achieve is the _looks_ of a tabular data. Do that with divs and not tables.